# Inline ReportViewer PDF cant open hyperlinks in new window

Tags: asp.net, pdf, reportviewer

I have a old report generated by ReportViewer in a webpage (Asp.Net). Changed so it's possible to genererate the report as a inline PDF in the same window via:

```
       byte[] bytes = Master.ReportViewer.LocalReport.Render(
           "PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding,
            out extension,
           out streamids, out warnings);

        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Report." + extension);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Purpose: Large reports tend to make the webpage unresponsive. The inline PDF don't have the same problem.

Problem: Hyperlinks can only open in the same window.

Anyone had the same problem? or has a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

How is your link look like?

Did you set up target of your hyperlink to "_blank"?

Comment: Problematic when I can't seem to set it for the hyperlink-tag in the reportdefinition (.rdlc)

Comment: what is your formula to generate hyperlink?

Comment: The reportviewer is the one generating the final hyperlink, thereof my problem. Otherwise I could use the PDF internal javascript method app.launchUrl.

Comment: Instead of giving reportviewer to generate links, are you able to create own formula which could generate html link for you?

Comment: Yepp. The links are generated before generating the report, but the problem is that I can't set any attributes other than the usual parameters. No _blank, _top etc.

Comment: Yepp? it means that you are in control of link generation?
What are the "usual parameters" for you?

Comment: Sorry for late response. The parameters where not unordinary. I ended up generating the reports as attachments for downloading instead. Not otpimal though.